# Automatically pick up a phone call on Google Hangouts, type a few keys, and hang up

Tags: google-hangouts

I am looking for a program, script or browser extension that can automatically pick up a phone call on Google Hangouts, type a few keys (random or prespecified), and hang up. It should only do so for some specified phone numbers.

It should work on Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X or Linux. Any price or license is fine.

I know I could use Sikuli, but I would rather prefer not to have to leave a Hangouts tab visible.

Comment: I haven't found any program so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.